# Examples of textbooks that use $\overline{\overline{A}}$ to denote set cardinality?

Tags: reference-request, notation

I was recently introduced to the notation $\overline{\overline{A}}$ to refer to the cardinality of a set $A$. (The dashes above the set of interest might be more closely spaced together.)

In the hundreds of books I have, I don't have a single textbook that uses this notation to refer to the cardinality of a set. What are some examples of books that do? (I'd be especially interested in one that covers measure theory, but this isn't necessary.)

As mentioned in the comments, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) also cites this notation as an example.

Comment: This is horrible notation... where did you come across it? $|A|$ is standard.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan My professor uses it, and you can also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

Comment: All I can hear in my head is swear words looking at that notation. Bar notation is commonly used for closure of a set in a topological space. This is just terrible notation and that is being kind. What on earth.

Comment: I think $\overline{\overline{\overline{\overline{\underline{\underline{A}}}}}}$ makes more sense

Comment: @DavidP Agree. Although it can be confused with $\underline{\underline{\overline{\overline{\overline{A}}}}}$ which has a thoroughly different meaning. A worthy price for elegance and restraint in notation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: It’s an old notation. Patrick Suppes uses it in his *Axiomatic Set Theory* (1960). For what it’s worth, he says that it stems from Cantor’s use of the double bar to indicate two levels of abstraction. I think that I’ve seen it in a few other older sources, too.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - yes, it is due to Cantor. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458669/why-was-the-cardinal-number-of-a-set-also-called-its-power-reference-cant).

Comment: @Mauro: Thanks!

Comment: The conclusion is: up to middle '70s it was the "standard" notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through some of the books I have where I thought it might be used and found it in the following books. The years given are for the edition in front of me, and the page numbers given are where I think it first appears in the book, which may not be where you’ll see it most used in the book.

**Axiomatic Set Theory** by Patrick Suppes (1960, p. 109)

**Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers** by Wacław Sierpiński (1965, p. 136)

**Set Theory** by K. Kuratowski and A. Mostowski (1968, p. 174)

**The Theory of Sets and Transfinite Arithmetic** by Alexander Abian (1965, p. 361)

**Introduction to Set Theory and Topology** by Kazimierz Kuratowski (1962, p. 61)

**Abstract Set Theory** by Abraham A. Fraenkel (1961, p. 60)

**The Theory of Sets and Transfinite Numbers** by B. Rotman and G. T. Kneebone (1966, p. 99)

**Abstract Set Theory** by Thoralf A. Skolem (1962, p.3)

**Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory** by Jean-Louis Krivine (1971, p. 23)

**Introduction to the Foundations of Mathematics** by Raymond L. Wilder (1965, p. 104)

**Introduction to Metamathematics** by Stephen Cole Kleene (1952, p. 9)

**Introduction to Mathematical Logic** by Elliott Mendelson (1979, p. 2)

**The Mathematics of Metamathematics** by Helena Rasiowa and Roman Sikorski (1963, p. 12)

**Sets, Lattices, and Boolean Algebras** by James C. Abbott (1969, p. 65)

**Boolean Rings** by Alexander Abian (1976, p. 9)

**Real and Abstract Analysis** by Edwin Hewitt and Karl Stromberg (1969, p. 19)

**Theory of Functions of a Real Variable** (Volume I) by I. P. Natanson (1961, p. 27)

**The Theory of Functions of Real Variables** by Lawrence M. Graves (1956, p. 308)

**The Theory of Functions of a Real Variable and the Theory of Fourier’s Series** (Volume I) by E. W. Hobson (1927, p. 203)

Comment: You can add Thoralf Skolem, [Abstract Set Theory (1962)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndml/1175197470), page 3 as well as Jean-Louis Krivine, [Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory (Engl.transl.1971, Springer)](https://books.google.it/books?id=X9nuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1), page 23.

Comment: Also Helena Rasiowa & Roman Sikorski, [The Mathematics of Metamathematics (Warsawa, 1963)](https://books.google.it/books?id=kYpsAAAAMAAJ), page 12

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA: The Rasiowa/Sikorski book has been on my "buy sometime" list for many years, and has recently risen close enough to the top that probably the next time I purchase some books from amazon, I'll try to get a reasonably decent copy of it. I know about the other two books (have checked them out from university libraries several times in the past 40+ years), but I don't have them and they're not on my "list". Of course, if I actually saw one of them at a used bookstore (unlikely), I'd buy it. I'll add these books to the list later, because there might be others suggested.